# Como validar campos vacios en un formulario en C#

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes camaradas esto tratando de validar los campos vacíos en un formulario en C# que contiene diferentes componentes, no se si este bien la condición que tengo ya que cuando doy clic al botón guardar y lleno todos campos me sale como quiera el mensaje que le asigne de completar los campos, o hay otra manera de hacer mas sencillo con otro procedimiento para validar los campos vacíos.

```
private void btnguardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        
   if (textnombre.Text == "" && cbxtipovehiculo.SelectedItem == null && textplaca.Text == "" && textlugarorigen.Text == "" && datefecha.Text == ""
            && radiocargada.Checked == true && radiodescargada.Checked == true && richTextobservacion.Text == ""
            && picturefoto.Image == null)
        {   
            string nombreChofer = textnombre.Text;
            string tipoVehiculo = cbxtipovehiculo.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string placas = textplaca.Text;
            string lugarOrigen = textlugarorigen.Text;
            string fecha = datefecha.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
            string contenido = string.Empty;

            if (radiocargada.Checked == true)
            {
                contenido = "Caja cargada";
            }
            if (radiodescargada.Checked == true)
            {
                contenido = "Caja descargada";
            }

            string observaciones = richTextobservacion.Text;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            picturefoto.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] aByte = ms.ToArray();

            MySqlConnection conexionBD = Conexion.conexion();
            conexionBD.Open();

            try
            {
                MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO entrada (nombreChofer,tipoVehiculo,placas," +
                "lugarOrigen,fecha,contenido,observaciones,foto) VALUES('" + nombreChofer + "','" + tipoVehiculo + "'," +
                "'" + placas + "','" + lugarOrigen + "','" + fecha + "','" + contenido + "','" + observaciones + "',@foto)", conexionBD);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("foto", aByte);
                comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Registro guardado con exito");
                limpiar();

            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Error al guardar: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                conexionBD.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Favor de completar los campos");
        }
    }
```

Comment: A ver, lo que quieres hacer es que si hay al menos un dato vacío salga un mensaje de que la información es inválida y no se puede guardar en la bd

Comment: Es correcto amigo

Comment: esa validacion la puedes hacer usando fluent validation y es mucho mejor o puedes usar este metodo que da c# [mira su uso aqui](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-isnullorempty-method/)

Comment: Dime cuales son los campos que son obligados llenar pa ayudarte

Comment: Quizas el campo que te da error y te hace falta la validacion es el cbxtipovehiculo, fijate si le cambias `cbxtipovehiculo.SelectedIndex >= 0`. Como haber otras formas, las hay, podes hacer algo manual, si lo vas a reutilizar podes descabellarte pensando, si son solo estos campos, quizas no vale la pena. Y como consejo a mi parecer tu boton los deberias dividir en 4 metodos distintos, ValidarCampos, CrearObjeto, ConexionDatos e CrearImagen, por decirte un ejemplo de nombres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La condición está al revés, si te fijas le estás diciendo que si alguno de los campos está vacío o son nulos los tiene que guardar y en caso contrario tiene que decirte que los completes. Por otro lado creo que es más limpio comprobar los strings con string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(). Quedaría así:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textnombre.Text) || cbxtipovehiculo.SelectedItem == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textplaca.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textlugarorigen.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(datefecha.Text) || radiocargada.Checked || radiodescargada.Checked || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(richTextobservacion.Text) || picturefoto.Image == null) {
            MessageBox.Show("Favor de completar los campos");
            return;
}
```

Comment: Me fue de gran ayuda tu respuesta nomas hice unos ajustes a los radioButton ya que cuando no seleccionaba ninguno como quiera me los guardaba en blanco.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejó una validación la cual te va a mostrar un mensaje con exactamente los campos que no cumplen con tu criterio de validación (campos vacíos, etcétera).

```
string sMensaje = "Se detectaron los siguientes errores:\n\n";
bool bError = false;

if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNombre.Text))
{
   sMensaje += "Nombre vacío\n";
   bError = true;
}

if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cbxTipoVehiculo.Text))//También podría ser usando cbxTipoVehiculo.SelectedItem == null
{
   sMensaje += "Tipo de vehículo vacío\n";
   bError = true;
}

if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPlaca.Text))
{ 
   sMensaje += "Placa vacía\n";
   bError = true;
}

if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLugarOrigen.Text))
{ 
   sMensaje += "Lugar de origen vacío\n";
   bError = true;
}

if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dateFecha.Text))
{ 
   sMensaje += "Fecha vacía\n";
   bError = true;
}

if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtObsevacion.Text))
{ 
   sMensaje += "Observación vacía\n";
   bError = true;
}

if(pictureInfo.Image == null)
{ 
   sMensaje += "Imagen vacía\n";
   bError = true;
}

if(bError)
{
   MessageBox.Show(sMensaje);
}
else
{
   //Código para guardar la información
}
```

Para las opciones de radio cargada y radio descargada con un solo **CheckBox** resuelves, Ej.: pondrías un solo **CheckBox** que se llamaría radio cargada, si está marcado entonces significa que está cargada, sino está marcado entonces no está cargada. También podrías emplear dos **RadioButton** como alternativa, uno con la opción cargada y el otro con la opción descargada (**RadioButton** no es lo mismo que **CheckBox**). Incluso podrías hacerlo con un **ComboBox**, donde seleccionarías el valor deseado.

Respecto a las fechas no quise complicarte y seguí tu lógica pero debes tener en cuenta que **Visual Studio** trae el control **MaskedTextBox** y **DateTimePicker** que permiten trabajar con las fechas de una manera más cómoda.

Ahora bien el código que te propongo va revisando dato por dato si ese campo esta vacío o no, de estar vacío pongo a **true** la **variable bError** y a la **variable sMensaje** le concateno que ese campo está vacío, **\n** significa salto de línea, como si hubieras apretado la **tecla Enter**. Por último pregunto si **bError** es **true** de serlo significa que hay al menos un campo vacío, por lo tanto mediante un mensaje muestro todos los campos vacíos, de **bError** ser **falso** entonces quiere decir que mi información es válida por tanto procedo a guardar la información en la base de datos.

Comment: Lo tomare en cuenta amigo Japv

Comment: @Miguel, tu sabras